# I have a crash when i tap the inbox icon using RZLTS push notifications service

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to integrate the RZLTS push notifications service into a objective-c game app.

While i have followed the exact steps provided by the RZLTS [documentation](http://rzlts.com/sdk/iOS_SDK_Integration_Guide.pdf) the app crashes when i tap the default inbox button.

Here you have my crash log from Xcode:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RZLTSInboxView setWebViewControllerBluredBGImage:webViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1701f8900'**

I have followed every step of the documentation. 
Here is my code for setting up the inbox button in the menuscene.m:

```
- (void)setButtonInbox {


    CGPoint inboxPosition = CGPointMake(POSITION_BUTTON_SOUND_WIDTH_MENUSCENE - 15,
                                        self.frame.size.height - SIZE_BUTTON_MORE_MENUSCENE * 2 - 10);

    RZLTSInboxView *inboxView = [[RZLTSInboxView alloc] initWithOrigin:inboxPosition
                                                            controller:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController
                                                               andType:InboxTypeICONWhite];
    [self.view addSubview:inboxView];

}
```

Here is my code for setting up the inbox GameViewController.m, ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [RZLTS startInbox:self
                appID:RZLTS_APP_ID
      developerSubID1:@""
      developerSubID2:@""
      developerSubID3:@""
            firstName:@"first"
             lastName:@"last"
                email:@"technical@firstlast.com"
               gender:BOTH
                  age:12];
```

Stack trace:

[image: Crash Stack Trace]

Comment: Does this method, `setWebViewControllerBluredBGImage:webViewController:`, actually exist for that class...or for something else?  Can you show a stack trace with symbols for the crash?

Comment: No, neither the method `setWebViewControllerBluredBGImage:webViewController:` exist, nor the call for such a method. So i'm not calling such a method anywhere in the project.

Comment: OK, so something in the stack trace should point to how it's getting called.

Comment: I have edited the post and added the stack trace of the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Stefan, thanks for bringing this up.  The team has deployed an update that resolves the issue.

The updated SDK is now available at: http://rzlts.com/sdk/RZLTS_iOS_v2.zip

Sam (from [RZLTS](http://rzlts.com))